# Sending Django celery task to AWS GPU

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery

I have a question related to designing the backend and frontend of an application that I'm currently working on. Although this might be more suited to AWS, I am asking here first because the community is great and very helpful.

I have developed an application that works well locally, but now I want to move it to the cloud. I'm facing some issues while doing so. The application is standalone and requires GPU for the celery task. The task is initiated when the user uploads an image, and once it's done, everything is saved and the GPU machine is turned off. However, the application needs to run continuously without requiring the GPU. The user should be able to login and see the dashboard and upload job process data anytime.

How can I achieve this? Should I separate my application into two parts? I have researched and found that many people suggest using AWS API, but before doing so, I need to know how to make a setup for it.

Has anyone done this combination of Django and AWS before? If not, what are you using for your ML inferences in production?

My appliction is working well in laptop. how to deploy server speratly in GPU machine. It access only if required.